# Invalid Procedure or Call for Creating Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following piece of code for creating a pivot table of a set of columns in my workbook.

```
  ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
  newname, Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
  newname & "!R7C1", TableName:=PivotTableName, _
  DefaultVersion:=6
```

This code runs perfectly fine on my machine and a lot of other peoples' machines. But for a few people, this is throwing Run Time Error 5: Invalid Procedure call or argument. What could the issue be?

Comment: What version of Excel are they using?  It might be that their `XlPivotTableVersionList` only goes up to 5, not 6

Comment: they are using 2013

Comment: What is the value of `newname`?

Comment: Also it's advisable to split the `PivotCache.Create` and the `.CreatePivotTable` into two lines.

Comment: newname is a parameter passed to the function. For example it is "SalesAnalysis"

Comment: How would one split the pivotchcache.create and .createpivottable?

Comment: What is the type of `newname`?

Comment: newname is a string.

Comment: Representing a table name? See the remarks in the [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69032905/invalid-procedure-or-call-for-creating-pivot-table).

Comment: Representing sheetname.

Comment: Get rid of `Version:=6`. Probably get rid of `DefaultVersion:=6` too. Both are optional parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `PivotCaches.Create` [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create):

**Parameters**

| Name | Required/Optional | Data type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Version | Optional | Variant | Version of the PivotTable. Version can be one of the `XlPivotTableVersionList` constants. |

The [xlPivotTableVersionList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpivottableversionlist) includes the following values:

| Name | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xlPivotTableVersion2000 | 0 | Excel 2000 |
| xlPivotTableVersion10 | 1 | Excel 2002 |
| xlPivotTableVersion11 | 2 | Excel 2003 |
| xlPivotTableVersion12 | 3 | Excel 2007 |
| xlPivotTableVersion14 | 4 | Excel 2010 |
| xlPivotTableVersion15 | 5 | Excel 2013 |
| xlPivotTableVersionCurrent | -1 | Provided only for backward compatibility |

I suspect newer versions of Excel may accept `6` and up as a parameter, but 2013 should not. In any case, this is an optional parameter and can be safely omitted.

Most likely `DefaultVersion:=6` can be omitted as well.

---

Side note: it's advisable to split the `PivotCache` and `PivotTable` creation into two steps.

```
Dim pCache As PivotCache
Set pCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _ 
                 SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                 SourceData:= newname)

Dim pTable As PivotTable
Set pTable = pCache.CreatePivotTable 
                 TableDestination:=newname & "!R7C1", _
                 TableName:=PivotTableName)
```

Comment: For Office365, `xlPivotTableVersionList` goes up to 7.  Not sure why they haven't updated the documentation since 2017.

Comment: @Chronocidal - I suspected as such. Where did you find that?

Comment: I opened Office365, hit "Record Macro", and made a PivotTable.  The resulting code had `Version:=7` in the `PivotCaches.Create`

Comment: Ah. I have Office 365, and I looked in the Object Browser... couldn't find any members past `xlPivotTableVersion15`. Seems that `Excel.XlPivotTableVersionList` hasn't actually been updated. So in a way the documentation is correct, and in a way it isn't.